# php email function does not print email values

Tags: php

i am using following code for email send

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);

$email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);

$mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);

$company = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['company']);

$qty = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['qty']);

//$upload = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['upload']);

$msg = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']);
}

$to="example@gmail.com";

$subject = "Order Information";

$message.= "FirstName: " . $name . "\n";

$message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

$message .= "ContactNo: " . $mobile . "\n";

$message .= "Company: " . $company . "\n";

$message .= "Quantity: " . $qty . "\n";

//$message .= "Upoload: " . $upload . "\n";

$msg = "Message: " . $msg . "\n";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
{   echo 'thank you';   }
else{ echo 'error';}

?>
```

it sends email successfully but ail fields in email message get as:
FirstName:
Email:
ContactNo:
Company:
Quantity:

please suggest what is wrong with code ???

Comment: because `$_POST['submit']` is not set.. add `name="submit"` attribute to the submit button in your form

Comment: Show us your HTML form.

Comment: i have set the name as follows <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send Request</button> but still gives same result...

Answer (score 0):

The value for submit is empty .. try with this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit" />
<button type="submit" name="btn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: what will be change in php mail code after adding this in html form ??? i have added second code in html form.

Comment: you dont need to change php mail code..

Comment: sorry still not worked...

Comment: i have edited like this...<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit" />
         <button type="submit" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send Request</button>

Comment: show me your html form

Comment: insead of if(isset($_POST['submit'])) use this if($_POST['submit'] !='')

Comment: if($_POST['submit'] !='')) added but no change. can't paste form code as comment box shows to long to post...

Comment: check your are getting form values in mail code file.. print_r($_POST);

Comment: only to post print_r($_POST); with mail function ? am i right ???

Comment: ($_POST['submit'] !=''))  its if($_POST['submit'] !=' ') right?

Comment: i have added like this if($_POST['submit'] !=''){print_r($_POST);}and also tried print_r with htmlspecialchars parameter but still same result...

Comment: i mean to add print_r($_POST) before if condition to check form values.. it will show like an array

Comment: better you show your code

Comment: i added as you said it echo the values. on mail.php and again got blank email.....what next ???

Comment: what about print_r($_REQUEST) ??

Comment: replace with print_r($_POST) ??

Comment: this print_r($_REQUEST) echo associative array and got blank email....

Comment: have you got any error?

Comment: this print_r($_REQUEST) echo associative array and gives blank email..

Comment: have you checked each variables values before sending mail like ..  echo $name; etcc?

Comment: thanks yuvraj , i don't know how but now this code is working thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Form method must using Post example :

```
<form method='POST' name='test'>your input n button </form>
```